# How to pass id from "input select" to its action?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Hello guys let me explain:

```
$this->view->form = new Application_Form_Kursdaty();

     $url = $this->view->url(
        array(
            'action' => 'details',
            'controller' => $this->getRequest()->getControllerName(),
            'module' => $this->getRequest()->getModuleName(),
            'id' => @@@@@SELECTFIELD[selected]@@@@@@
        ),
        'default',
        true
    );
    $this->view->form->setAction($url);
```

I basically want my select field to redirect to page which i choose.
I dont really know what to do, please help!

Comment: You need it to redirect when user selects an option from select directly from browser, or after form gets sent to server and processed?

Comment: After form clicking submit ! otherwise i would use js

Comment: in your code is your form constructor populating form values?

Answer (score 1):

If your form is instance of `Zend_Form` and populated with sent data then you can use `$form->getValue($nameOfField)` or `$form->getElement($elementName)->getValue()`

Comment: I use something like this:

$this->view->form = new Application_Form_Kursdaty(array('daty' => $lol2,'idkurs' => $id));

and in form i have
'multiOptions' => $this->_daty

Your solution doesnt work for my select :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem!

The value of the select element is not set until after the submit button is pressed. So you don't have access to the value until after the post.

So a way to do what you want to do in PHP would be to use 2 actions. The first action takes the post and performs the validation then you could take the data and forward it to the action of your choice depending on the value of that select.

```
public function formAction() {
    $form = new Form();
    $form->setAction('/url');

    if ($this->_request->isPost()){
        if ($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()){
            $select = $form->getValue('select');
            switch($select) {
                case ('value1') :
                    $this->_forward('action');
                    break;
                case ('value2') :
                     $this->_forward('action');
                     break;
                default :
                      $this->_forward('action');
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->view->form = $form
}
```

This might be the kind of work flow you would look at for the first action. You'll need to work out the details but a `_forward` should be doable in this instance as it should perform the redirect without losing the current request object.